# Custom field migration issue

Tags: deployment, lookup, ant

I am trying to move a lookup field but I am getting an error:

> referenceTo value of 'xxxxxx__c' does not resolve to a valid sObject type.

Comment: If the lookup is to a parent type not in the target org, you can't deploy the field alone...you have to include that parent type.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thank you! The objects api name in target org was changed and i did not consider it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Triple check that you have the parent object present in the target org. Having it missing is the only reason you would get such an error.